# Inconsistent Display in IE

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, html

So, I'm having displays issue in IE, but I'm confused because it's an inconsistent issue.

Basically, my index page in IE is screwed up. You can see it here: http://www.studentbridges.org

But when you go to another page of the website, everything is displayed fine. Like here: http://www.studentbridges.org/for-community-members/

I really can not figure out what the difference is between my index page and the rest of my pages that scres up the index page so, especially when the index page displays fine in all pother browsers...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I use WordPress if that helps.

Comment: which IE? you can make a replica of the index page and start removing content until the page display correctly to narrow down the issue. But first thing first, which IE version?

Comment: Noelle, questions on SO should be self-contained rather than a description and a link. For details please see: [Something in my project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: there is a javascript error on your homepage in IE8

Comment: George: Note taken. I will try to debug and make it more specific.

Comment: Huangism: Hmmm... I will go through my javascripts and try and figure out which one is causing the issue. What tool are you using that made this clear to you?

Comment: @Noelle if you have the status bar shown, there is a error icon with exclamation mark on it. The error really doesn't say much but it's a start.

Comment: Run IE, go to your site, press `F12`, select the "Script" tab. Click "Start Debugging". Go back to the browser, refresh.

Comment: @Noelle most likely caused by the script that displays the right side content. On IE8 the content does not appear (right of the twitter feed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a comment before the DOCTYPE declaration on your home page but not on the other page in your example, which seems to be throwing IE into quirks mode. In order for IE to render in standards mode, the DOCTYPE must be the first thing in the HTML. No empty lines or comments are allowed.

Comment: Oh my gosh. Such a simple fix. I've been trying to fix this error for MONTHS and it was litterally something I never thought of... Thank you so much. This worked.

Comment: Yes, sorry! Just did! Thanks again!